# How to join elements as strings with a delimiter from a group of arrays column-wise

Tags: python, string-concatenation

I have the following arrays (all the same length):

```
array_1=[1,2,3]
array_2=[4,5,6]
array_3=[7,8,9]
```

What I need is to concatenate each element in both arrays to get:

```
array_4=['1-4-7','2-5-8','3-6-9']
```

This has to be done over about 30000 records, so I was looking for something compact.

Comment: _"This has to be done over about 30000 records, so I was looking for something compact, "_ You mean something _fast_?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Perhaps `str.join()`? Was it not sufficient for your problem?

Comment: How are your arrays stored? Surely not as `array_1=[1, 2, 3], ..., array_30000=[4, 5, 6]`? This can make a big difference in the approach.

Answer (score 7):

Use `zip()` to isolate the columns, `str()` to create strings from each element, and `str.join()` to join the stringified elments together.

```
array_1=[1,2,3]
array_2=[4,5,6]
array_3=[7,8,9]

meta_array = [array_1, array_2, array_3]
array_4 = ['-'.join(str(item) for item in column) for column in zip(*meta_array)]

assert array_4==['1-4-7','2-5-8','3-6-9']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using [`numpy.column_stack()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
import numpy as np
array_1=[1,2,3]
array_2=[4,5,6]
array_3=[7,8,9]

col_stacked = np.column_stack([array_1, array_2, array_3])
print(col_stacked)
#array([[1, 4, 7],
#       [2, 5, 8],
#       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Now simply iterate through `col_stacked` and join the values with `"-"`. First we need to convert the values to `str`, which can be done using `map()`:

```
array_4 = ["-".join(map(str, a)) for a in col_stacked]
print(array_4)
#['1-4-7', '2-5-8', '3-6-9']
```

**Note**: `column_stack()` only works if all of the arrays have the same length.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you want to have a new array of strings with the elements from a certain position from **all arrays**. If the number of arrays is small, the following code should be a possible solution:

```
for index in range(len(array_1)):
    newFormedElement = str(array_1[index]) + '-' + str(array_2[index]) + '-' + str(array_3[index])
    array_4.append(newFormedElement)
```

Assuming that by **records**, you meant number of elements in your array(s).
But if you are working with 30000 arrays you might want to use [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) and iterate throughout the list of arrays.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for not using the proper jargon, by records I meant number of elements in the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting:

```
array_1=[1,2,3]
array_2=[4,5,6]
array_3=[7,8,9]
last_result = ['{}-{}-{}'.format(*i) for i in zip(array_1, array_2, array_3)]
```

Output:

```
['1-4-7', '2-5-8', '3-6-9']
```